# Laravel project on heroku with db4free not creating new users

Tags: mysql, laravel, heroku, laravel-8

I've got my laravel project deployed on heroku, I finally got almost everything working, I have the Procfile which changes the home directory, and my CSS doesn't give mixed content errors anymore.

I've set up a database with db4free.net, and set up the env file accordingly, I've also set up the heroku config vars as well.

Using the Heroku CLI I ran bash, and migrated, this did create the tables correctly. The issue I'm facing now is that when I go to register, it seems to have worked and redirects to the homepage, however the data is never entered to the DB so I cannot log in with these details.

I haven't changed anything to do with the registering code thats provided in the auth package.

Answer (score 0):

So it WAS all working, Heroku and especially db4free are pretty slow at updating